# Substituting a value into a subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.game, 
(
SELECT AVG(dd.DUR) as median_val
FROM (
SELECT  S.val AS DUR, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as `row_number`, @total_rows:=@rownum
  FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, M.date_start, M.date_finished) as val FROM matches M INNER JOIN tournaments T ON M.tournament_id=T.id
  WHERE M.tournament_id NOT IN (5,6) AND T.game = 'EXAMPLE'
  ORDER BY val) S, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
) as dd
WHERE dd.row_number IN (FLOOR((@total_rows+1)/2), FLOOR((@total_rows+2)/2))
) AS duration
FROM matches M INNER JOIN tournaments P ON M.tournament_id=P.id WHERE P.id NOT IN (5,6) GROUP BY P.game
```

It works, but all the second col values are the same because of `T.game = 'EXAMPLE'`
How can i put P.game value from first SELECT instead of EXAMPLE constant?

Table tournaments

```
CREATE TABLE tournaments (id INT PRIMARY KEY, game VARCHAR(64));
INSERT INTO tournaments (`id`, `game`) VALUES ('1', 'EXAMPLE'), ('2', 'TETRIS'), ('3', 'MARIO'), ('4', 'EXAMPLE'), ('5', 'TETRIS'), ('6', 'MARIO');
id | game
-------------
 1    EXAMPLE
 2    TETRIS
 3    MARIO
 4    EXAMPLE
 5    TETRIS
 6    MARIO
```

Table matches

```
CREATE TABLE matches (id INT PRIMARY KEY, tournament_id INT, date_start DATETIME, date_finished DATETIME);
INSERT INTO matches (`id`, `tournament_id`, `date_start`, `date_finished`) VALUES ('1', '1', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:12:00'), ('2', '2', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:18:00'), ('3', '3', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:16:00'), ('4', '3', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:22:00'), ('5', '2', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:31:00'), ('6', '1', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:19:00'), ('7', '2', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:45:00'), ('8', '4', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:28:00'), ('9', '4', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:54:00'), ('10', '5', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:12:00'), ('11', '6', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:18:00'), ('12', '7', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:16:00'), ('13', '7', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:22:00'), ('14', '6', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:31:00'), ('15', '5', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:19:00'), ('16', '6', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:45:00'), ('17', '6', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:28:00'), ('18', '5', '2024-01-18 01:10:00', '2024-01-18 01:54:00');

id | tournament_id |     date_start     |     date_finished     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1          1         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:12:00
2          2         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:18:00
3          3         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:16:00
4          3         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:22:00
5          2         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:31:00
6          1         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:19:00
7          2         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:45:00
8          4         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:28:00
9          4         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:54:00
10         5         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:12:00
11         6         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:18:00
12         7         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:16:00
13         7         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:22:00
14         6         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:31:00
15         5         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:19:00
16         6         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:45:00
17         6         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:28:00
18         5         2024-01-18 01:10:00   2024-01-18 01:54:00
```

I'm expecting a table with different values of the second column counted for the values of the first column. Duration is a median value of time difference - TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, M.date_start, M.date_finished)

```
game     | duration
-------------------
EXAMPLE      13.5
TETRIS       21
MARIO        9
```

Comment: which mysql version are you using, mysql 8 gas window functions. also please add CREATE TABLE for all tables involved INSERT INTO  for basic data and wanted result as formatted text

Comment: Unfortunately its only 5.7.
I have added example tables and a table with the result

Comment: Provide reproduceable sample code according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) #5. Also provide desired output according to #3, with detailed explanations.

Comment: The published query query cannot produce output for EXAMPLE because you are excluding tournament_id  1 (examples id)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Changed 1 to 11 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the median you need somewhat more complex data.

Below works, but you really should think about MYsql 8.x, which makes it somewhat simpler

```
SELECT 
t.`tournament_id`
, ta.game
, avg(`val`) as `median`
FROM
(
    SELECT
        `tournament_id`,
        `val`,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM `matches` `t2` WHERE `t2`.`tournament_id` = `t3`.`tournament_id`) as `ct`,
        `seq`,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM `matches` `t2` WHERE `t2`.`tournament_id` < `t3`.`tournament_id`) as `delta`

    FROM
        (SELECT `tournament_id`, `val`, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as `seq`
        FROM (SELECT `tournament_id`, (TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, date_start, date_finished)) `val` FROM `matches` ORDER BY `tournament_id`, `val`) as `t2`
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) as `x`
        ORDER BY `tournament_id`, `seq`) as `t3`
    HAVING
        (`ct`%2 = 0 and `seq`-`delta` between floor((`ct`+1)/2) and floor((`ct`+1)/2) +1)
        or (`ct`%2 <> 0 and `seq`-`delta` = (`ct`+1)/2)
) as `t` JOIN tournaments ta ON ta.id = t.tournament_id

GROUP BY `tournament_id`,ta.game
ORDER BY `tournament_id`;
```

| tournament_id | game | median |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EXAMPLE | 5.5000 |
| 2 | TETRIS | 21.0000 |
| 3 | MARIO | 15.0000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2CkMJWvt)

For the new data you need to adept the approach

```
SELECT 
 t.game
, avg(`val`) as `median`
FROM
(
    SELECT
        `game`,
        `val`,
        (SELECT count(*) 
           FROM `matches` `t2` JOIN tournaments ta ON ta.id = t2.tournament_id
          WHERE `ta`.`game` = `t3`.`game` AND ta.id NOT IN (5, 6)) as `ct`,
        `seq`,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM `matches` `t2` JOIN tournaments ta ON ta.id = t2.tournament_id
         WHERE `ta`.`game` < `t3`.`game`  AND ta.id NOT IN (5, 6)) as `delta`

    FROM
        (SELECT `game`, `val`, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as `seq`
        FROM (SELECT `game`, (TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, date_start, date_finished)) `val` 
               FROM `matches` m JOIN tournaments ta ON ta.id = m.tournament_id
              WHERE ta.id NOT IN (5, 6)
               ORDER BY `game`, `val`) as `t2`
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) as `x`
        ORDER BY `game`, `seq`) as `t3`
    HAVING
        (`ct`%2 = 0 and `seq`-`delta` between floor((`ct`+1)/2) and floor((`ct`+1)/2) +1)
        or (`ct`%2 <> 0 and `seq`-`delta` = (`ct`+1)/2)
) as `t` 

GROUP BY t.game
ORDER BY t.game;
```

| game | median |
| --- | --- |
| EXAMPLE | 13.5000 |
| MARIO | 9.0000 |
| TETRIS | 21.0000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2Z3Hi7Iu)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But this query does not take into account the possibility of repeating game values. The ability to exclude some tournaments by ID has also been removed. I adjusted the INSERT INTO for both tables and recalculated the desired result. Now in the example there is a repeating game and it is necessary to exclude tournaments with id 5 and 6.

Comment: you specified that the tournament id should b present as every column has to be in the GROUP BY or have an aggregation  this is the correct solution, for your query simp,ly remove the tournament id from the SELECT and GROUÜ BY and it works just fine

Comment: Removed tournament id from select and group by. I added a condition tournament id NOT IN (5, 6). 5 and 6 ids are excluded, but for EXAMPLE I get the wrong value. It is not the median for 4 values that is calculated, but the average of two separate medians for each id. I expecting median = 13,5 (2, 9, 18, 44). But i`ve got 18,25 ( (((2+9)/2) + ((18+44)/2))/2 ). Could you please correct your example in fiddle

Comment: changing the basis of the question needs to get a new question, adepting it is the wrong to get your answers. i still chnanged the query to fit your needs